# I have control to EIP but no have idea when put the shellcode - not have any dll return adress

Tags: buffer-overflow, stack

for the practice i take some C code and compiled
i try put shellcode open some calc
and i not have idea which method i need to use

[image]
[image]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)


{
char buff[120];
int pass = 0;

printf("\n Enter the password : \n");
gets(buff);

if(strcmp(buff, "thegeekstuff"))
{
    printf ("\n Wrong Password \n");
}
else
{
    printf ("\n Correct Password \n");
    pass = 1;
}

if(pass)
{
   /* Now Give root or admin rights to user*/
    printf ("\n Buffer success \n");
}

return 0;
```

}

what the problem ?

Comment: You need to locate the address of the input first. Then you put the shellcode somewhere in the input. Calculate the effective address of the shellcode then and put in the packed address(\x01\xef\xcd\xab for 0xabcdef01) in place of BBBB. Follow the tutorial carefully which you're trying. Read on the materials suggested/provided.

Comment: @sudhackar 
ok i find i can use kernel32.dll to return address 
the address is "77C6F8F7" 
i use this site to change hex2ascii
http://iptuga.com/conversor.php

i input 136*A+F7F8C677+160*"/x90"

i do simple copy paste the output website
and the program crash

i really wonder what the problem

i check the kernel address with another program , crush it and the calc open...

whats wrong?

Comment: can you please paste the code as text instead of a blurry screenshot?

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky the code is one line when i paste it

#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(void)
{
    char buff[120];
    int pass = 0;

    printf("\n Enter the password : \n");
    gets(buff);

    if(strcmp(buff, "thegeekstuff"))
    {
        printf ("\n Wrong Password \n");
    }
    else
    {
        printf ("\n Correct Password \n");
        pass = 1;
    }

    if(pass)
    {
       /* Now Give root or admin rights to user*/
        printf ("\n Buffer success \n");
    }

    return 0;
}

Comment: Please edit the question and put the code instead of picture, thanks.

Comment: I wrote an answer based on your possible goals. For further help, you can share the tutorial address for us to look at.

Comment: @IgorSkochinsky i edit the question with the code

Comment: @de6f
when i try return to kernel32.dll -- 7611F8F7 

something wrong

Answer (score 1):

I don't know what you're trying to accomplish here, but you can overwrite* `pass` to correct second if statement as you did accidentally on the picture.

If you are determined to use shellcode, find a memory area you can continuously overflow your input and use that address to replace *BBBB*.  Another option is returning to a Windows API; then you must correctly set arguments before calling function and bypass ASLR.

* Since some compilers can place buffers immediately after return value, I assume `pass` variable stored higher addresses than `buff` and you overwrote it.